# Browserify(-shim) the gauss statistics library

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I'm having a hard time using the gauss statistics library, which is available as an npm module, in a browserify context.

I'm using

```
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "4.2.3",
  "gauss": "0.2.12"
}
```

and the following simple entry script:

```
// app.js

var gauss = require('gauss');

var v = new gauss.Vector([1, 2, 3]);

console.log('It works: ' + v);
```

When I `browserify` this and load the resulting bundle in the browser, I get a `TypeError: object is not a function` error, while in node, everything works as expected.

I guess the problem has to do with how the library tries to expose itself, because it works when I manually add something like

```
if (window.gauss) {
  module.exports = window.gauss;
}
```

to the main file of `gauss`.

I've tried various `browserify-shim` configurations, all of which lead to a different error down the road.

Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/shimikano/shim-gauss) to play around with.

Can anyone come up with a solution that doesn't involve manual patching?

**Edit: More Info**

The exception is thrown when I try to call `new gauss.Vector()`. `gauss.Vector` is defined, but not a function.

If I change my `app.js` to just

```
var gauss = require('gauss');
console.log(gauss);
```

then in node, I get

```
{ version: '0.2.12',
  Collection: [Function],
  Vector: [Function],
  TimeSeries: [Function] }
```

as expected. However, in the browser, this is logged (note `Vector` being an `Object`):

```
Object {version: "0.2.12", Collection: Object, Vector: Object, TimeSeries: Object}
```

As stated above, I suspect the culprit to be some code that [conditionally exposes](https://github.com/wayoutmind/gauss/blob/master/lib/vector.js#L652) the library, but I don't really know how I could tackle this.

A simple browserify-shim configuration like

```
"browser": {
  "gauss": "./node_modules/gauss/index.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "gauss": { "exports": "gauss" }
},
```

resulted in `Error: Cannot find module './lib/gauss'` both in node and the browser (`./lib/gauss` is required in `gauss/index.js`).

Comment: Can you narrow down the point where the error is thrown or explain any debugging steps you've taken and the result of them?

Comment: Any answers for this question? I am facing a similar problem